# how to get the x labels to be in the same order?

Tags: python, visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

[image]

how to get the x labels to be in the same order?

i want the x labels to be in the same order.
in the top and bottom pictures, the order of 'Ya' and 'Tidak' is different

Answer (score 0):

Use `order` as parameter of [`sns.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

```
x_order = sorted(data['Polydipsia'].unique())

sns.countplot(data['Polydipsia'], hue=data['Kelas'], order=x_order)
```

Comment: If the syntax is like that, how to change the x labels to be the same?

data_cat=data[['Polydipsia', 'Polyuria']]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(50,55)) 
for indx,val in enumerate(data_cat.columns):
    ax=plt.subplot(10,6,indx+1)
    ax.set_title(val,fontweight='bold',fontfamily='serif')
    for i in ['right','top']:
        ax.spines[i].set_visible(False)
    ax.grid(linestyle=':',axis='y')
    sns.countplot(data_cat[val],hue=data['Kelas'])

Comment: please what is the output of `data_cat.head()`

Comment: actually the same as the image above, but in this syntax I want to make 2 images into 1 image

Comment: Use `order=['Tidak', 'Ya']` to force the column order.